# C# Microsoft authentication redirect uri

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

So I have a C# web api using a Microsoft authentication. Now when I try it on localhost with a http://localhost:port redirect URI setup in [Microsoft Apps](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com)
it is working. But when I deploy my app with an IP address so I try to change my redirect URI into the IP of my server, it doesn't work anymore. First of all the redirect URI field in Microsoft apps doesn't accept non-https url except for http://localhost which it accepts. So out of ideas, I try to put https://my-ip-address on the redirect URI, still doesn't work. I'm getting the `This site can’t be reached` error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you navigate to https://my-ip-address, do you get to your site? how did you host it? using IIS?

Comment: No, it doesn't go to my site. Just an error `This site can’t be reached`. And yeah I hosted it using IIS.

Comment: you first need to solve the problem of navigating to https://my-ip-address without the [Authorize] attribute set on your controller/Web end point. There are a number of things to check:
- is IIS configured to allow anonymous authentication (since your app will do the auth, from IIS's point of view this should just pass)
- don't you have certificates issues (for SSL)

Comment: No I need the [Authorize] attribute on my controller. My problem here is that apps portal doesn't accept non https URL but it allows localhost to be http. So when I deploy my app into a domain does that mean that it has to be an https domain?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. Of course you need it the [Authorize] attribute. What I meant is remove it temporarily to check that IIS was not blocking first (before you application). And, yes this is a current limitation of the V2 applications. The URL needs to be https: (even on premise).

Answer (score 0):

Jed. You are right: with the applications created with the [application registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) (V2 apps), there are limitations specifically on redirect URLs. See [Restrictions on redirect URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-redirect-uris)

Comment: So what will be the resolution for this? Is there a workaround or something?

Comment: I added 2 questions above